# Module not found API Moip in Angular 5

Tags: node.js, angular, api, typescript, npm

### What do I need to do to import and use the Moip SDK correctly without error?

I am trying to integrate into my Angular application the Moip API using https://github.com/moip/moip-sdk-node.

When running the code below in my **moip-api.service.ts** file, an error is occurring.

```
import moipSdk from 'moip-sdk-node'
const moip = moipSdk({
  token: 'your-access-token',
  key: 'your-access-key',
  production: false
});
```

**In Visual Studio Code:**

> Try `npm install @types/moip-sdk-node` if it exists or add a new
>   declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'moip-sdk-node';`

**In cmd.exe Running ng serve:**

```
 ERROR in ./node_modules/moip-sdk-node/dist/client/api.js Module not
 found: Error: Can't resolve '../../package' in
 'C:\dev\allclinics\node_modules\moip-sdk-node\dist\client' ERROR in
 ./node_modules/moip-sdk-node/dist/client/api_assinaturas.js
```

[image]

Comment: I am not sure what is your use case but shouldn't you be using the web sdk? https://github.com/moip/moip-sdk-js

Comment: This SDK is for doing credit card encryption, I need to import into my moip-sdk-node project, because it is in it that contains the methods I need, otherwise I will have to create methods in a POST, GET, PUT, DELETE service using HTTP of the Angular.